# How to manage development credentials vs generic (example) ones?

Tags: deployment, authentication, configuration

I am an amateur developper and would like to share some of my code via GitHub or GitLabs.

The problem I am trying to resolve is that I have a configuration file with my real credentials (used during development) and would like to provide a generic one (with placehholders for the credentials) -- all this without changing the code.

In practical terms I have today (in pseudo-code)

```
arguments = yaml.read("configuration.yaml")
```

and would like to avoid dragging a

```
# do not forget to switch the config files before pushing to github
arguments = yaml.read("configuration-dev.yaml")
#arguments = yaml.read("configuration.yaml")
```

**Is there an established method for such issues?** (generally speaking - elements in code which are specific to an installation, but with the need to send generic/placeholder entries)

Note: I am mostly developping in Python if it makes an approach easier

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure these are the *established* methods, nonetheless the often seen approach is to use either environment variables or config merging.

### Using Env variables

This allows you to specify a default config or, when a certain `ENV_VAR` is defined, to use that environment var.

The example code would be (using Python's ConfigParser INI files):

```
config_path = os.environ.get('ENV_VAR', 'default_config.ini')
config = ConfigParser()
config.read(config_path)
```

The advantage is that you could use the same method to deploy with a `production_config.ini`. Just call your code as:

```
$ ENV_VAR='prod_config.ini' my_python_script.py
```

### Using config merging

Again, [Python's ConfigParser allows you to read a list of config files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read), where options defined in successive files overwrite previous ones. If specified files do not exist, they are ignored. This is effectively config merging.

```
(...)
config.read(['generic_config.ini', 'local_config.ini'])
```

If you're using YAML you might need to provide [custom logic for config merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823196/yaml-merge-in-python).

In both cases, the `local_config.ini` should be ignored and not committed to the repository. This allows every team member/contributor to have his/her own `local_config.ini` automatically used.

## Make sure never to commit credentials to the code repository!